# Display indices of the list

Tags: list-manipulation

```
data = List[RandomVariate[ExponentialDistribution[2], 200]] // Sort;
list = List[Table[i, {i, 0, 200}]];
d2=Riffle[{data},{list}]
Partition[d2,2]
```

This gives me one list joined with the other. I want to have the elements of both the lists interleaved with each other. So that I cam later partition them.

Comment: You are just using superflous `List`/braces. Try `data = RandomVariate[ExponentialDistribution[2], 200] // Sort;
list = Table[i, {i, 0, 200}];
d2 = Riffle[data, list]`

Comment: see also  [MapIndexed](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MapIndexed.html) in the docs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an easy way to do what you want.

```
SeedRandom[42];
  Module[{n = 10, data},
    data = RandomVariate[ExponentialDistribution[2], n] // Sort;
    Transpose[{data, Range[n]}]]
```

> ```
> {{0.0135188, 1}, {0.293526, 2}, {0.395115, 3}, {0.426769, 4}, {0.469494, 5}, 
>  {0.529115, 6}, {0.561704, 7}, {0.607267, 8}, {0.620372, 9}, {0.788951, 10}}
> ```